# Are Windows API Interlocked Singly Linked Lists really lock free?

Tags: c++, windows

This question is related to [Windows API Interlocked Singly Linked Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/interlocked-singly-linked-lists).
The documentation states that: "SLists are implemented using a nonblocking algorithm to provide atomic synchronization."

I did a little bit of debugging and the singly linked list functions seem to use SRW locks internally on Windows 10. I would think that this means they are not really lock free.

Could you please tell me if there is something that I missed?

Comment: Slow down, take a step back and consider readers who don't have your context. So some implementation (?) of SLL is being advertised (??) as lock-free but you found (???) it to have some locking. You might want to add details about all of the above into your question.

Comment: Many data structures are only mostly lock-free. Because if you fail to make progress due to heavy contention, it is a better idea to let the OS take over. That is probably what's going on.

Comment: Yes, RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive() implements a slim reader/writer lock.  "Slim" being the operative term, the lock is non-blocking and doesn't require a kernel call.  It can be non-blocking since the lock is held for mere nanoseconds while the list is being modified.

Comment: @HansPassant how does this work under heavy load? bad or very bad?

Comment: Thank you everybody for providing comments to this ticket. 
Thank you dratenik for making me aware that the question is not clear enough. Hopefully the latest changes provide the necessary details.
HansPassant you might be on to something. However, as Surt pointed out it is possible for the thread holding the lock to be preempted and then all the other threads using the objects will be blocked. I was expecting some kind of algorithm using the compare-and-swap idiom.

Answer (score 1):

There're actually two versions. The x64 version uses CAS primitive and is lock free (you can look at the deassembly of your x64 program). The x86 WOW64 version uses slim lock.